# Kendo Grid: How to disable "filterable" on data-column definition?

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have defined a kendo grid declaratively with a `data-columns` attribute. Some columns have a `"filterable": ...` attribute defined, and some don't. The ones that do not have it defined still show the filter textbox with all of the options "Equal to", "Starts with", ... etc.

I would like to have no filter textbox at all on these columns for which I've not defined the attribute.

How can I explicitly remove the filter textbox?

My grid definition:

```
<div id="Checkpoints">
    <div data-filterable='{ "mode": "row" }'
         data-role='grid'
         data-sortable='true'
         data-bind='source: reportData.CheckpointExceptions'
         data-pageable='{ "pageSize": 10 }'


         data-toolbar='["excel"]'
         data-excel='{ "fileName": "CheckpointExceptionExport.xlsx", "allPages": "true" }'
         data-excelExport='e -> excelExportHelper(e)'

         data-columns='[
            {
                "field": "checkpoint_name", 
                "title": "Checkpoint", 
                "filterable": { "cell": { "operator": "contains"}}},
            {
                "field": "location_name", 
                "title": "Location", 
                "filterable": { "cell": { "operator": "contains"}}
            },
            {
                "field": "patrolled_by", 
                "title": "Patrolled By", 
                "filterable": { "cell": { "operator": "contains"}}
            },
            {
                "field": "geotag",
                "title": "GeoTag", 
                "template": kendo.template($("#geotagTemplate").html()) 
            },
        {
            "field": "geofence",
            "title": "GeoFence",   
            "template": kendo.template($("#geofenceTemplate").html())
        },
        {
            "field": "completed",
            "title": "Completed",
            "template": kendo.template($("#completedTemplate").html())
        },
        {
            "field": "gps",
            "title": "GPS", 
            "template": kendo.template($("#gpsTemplate").html())
        },
        {
            "title": "", 
            "template": kendo.template($("#viewLinkTemplate").html())
        }
    ]'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the `filterable` property for the fields you do not want to be filterable, then explicitly set it to `false`, as it's done in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/korchev/kEqYh/3/).

Comment: Fantastic thanks I thought it was something simple like that but could not find it. I had tried `"none"` to no avail.